# sorting an array of strings with qsort function

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, quicksort, qsort

I'm sorting an array of strings by using the `qsort` function.

```
char treeName[100][31];
```

By trial and error, I figured out that it should be done like this:

```
qsort(&treeName[0], count, sizeof(*treeName), Comparar_nome);
```

However, I am not entirely sure why `sizeof(*treeName)`. Shouldn't it be `sizeof(char) * 31`, or something like that?

Comment: Did you try using `sizeof(char) * 31`?  It should work as well as either `sizeof(*treeName)` or `sizeof(treeName[0])` (or slightly less plausible constructs, such as `sizeof(char[31])`).  All of these evaluate to the same number — `31`.

Comment: Post `Comparar_nome().`

Answer (score 1):

```
   qsort(&treeName[0], count, sizeof(*treeName),Comparar_nome);
```

Can be broken down as follows:

```
    qsort
```

The function call.

```
    &treeName[0]
```

Address of the start of the array. Can be simplified to `treeName`.

```
    count
```

The number of entries in `treeName` actually used.

```
    sizeof(*treeName)
```

The size of an array element. I would have written this is `sizeof(treename[0])` but there's no difference. `sizeof(char)*31` really should have worked. Are you sure you didn't have something else broken when you tried it? We were unable to find a real compiler for which this would not work. `sizeof(*treename)` is better anyway for readability and should that `31` ever change.

```
    Comparar_nome
```

Address of the function that compares tree nodes. You wrote it correctly; `&Comparar_nome` is archaic style.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242702/discussion-on-answer-by-joshua-sorting-an-array-of-strings-with-qsort-function).

Answer (score 1):

If `treeName` is indeed defined as `char treeName[100][31];` in the scope of the function calling `qsort`, your code is correct:

```
qsort(&treeName[0], count, sizeof(*treeName), Comparar_nome);
```

You could write this equivalently:

```
qsort(treeName, count, sizeof treeName[0], Comparar_nome);
```

Note however that `Comparar_nome` must have the correct prototype:

```
int Comparar_nome(const void *a, const void *b);
```

A simple implementation being:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Comparar_nome(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp(a, b);
}
```

Passing `strcmp` instead of `Comparar_nome` would be a type mismatch invoking undefined behavior that would go unnoticed in many architectures but is nevertheless incorrect.